# How to study for the Algorithm courses

Tags: algorithms

I'm taking a fairly challenging Algorithm course, in which we are learning about algorithms such as Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford etc. as well as the algorithm design patterns such as recursions, DP and various graph construction techniques such as layering. Now I really have some trouble to design correct and efficient algorithm using stuff we learned in the class. To be specific, I'm having trouble with following:

- Design an algorithm that's fast enough, i.e., I came up with a $O(n^2)$ algorithm but in fact there is a $O(n log n)$ algorithm.
- To find the edge cases for the algorithm I designed. It happened a lot of times to me during exam that I designed some seemingly correct algorithm but will actual fail in some edge cases. I always have some hard time to find those edge cases and therefore falsely believe the algorithm is correct.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions that can help me deal with my struggle. Also, just for reference, here are the links to the course I'm taking ([schedule](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs374/lectures.html), and the [homeworks](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs374/work.html))

Comment: Hi, and welcome to CS!  This question isn't really on-topic for this site, but with regards to edge cases, I can share with you some things that seem to frequently trap my students. When appropriate, consider empty sets and singletons (arrays, trees, etc, with only one member).  When dealing with binary trees, make sure you deal with one descendant missing, the other missing, and both missing.  Also, if appropriate, make sure you handle zero and negative numbers.  I'd say that, put together, those gets about 95% of the edge cases my students regularly miss.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. But do you have any suggestions for the graph construction and NFA and DFA construction problems?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designing algorithms that are fast enough is probably a function of experience. There are strategies (recursion, divide-and-conquer, dynamic programming...) that can be used. Often a problem can be approached with multiple strategies but one is more efficient than the other. The more of these strategies you know, the better you are equipped for using them in your algorithms. Experience will also give you a feel for what is an appropriate approach; you may intuitively notice which problems are recursive in nature, which can be expressed as operations on a graph etc. Then you can use what you know to knead the challenge into a familiar shape. Do a Google search for "algorithm strategies" to find useful resources which list generic strategies. Learn about these and then consider for algorithms you encounter how they are instances of these generic approaches (or combinations thereof).

Edge cases tend to occur where **assumptions** are made, and for some situations those assumptions are incorrect. An algorithm attempts to resolve something for some structure which seems consistent; it breaks down where the structure suddenly differs or becomes inconsistent. Edge cases are the sort of place in a program where you need to test assumptions and where decisions branch.

For example, suppose I have some algorithm that takes a list of elements as input and performs a computation over it. You begin your design by stating that for each element in the list, in order, some action is performed. That's an assumption right there. "Each element in the list" assumes there are some. How will it behave for an empty list?

An example of this I encountered in some programming contest a while ago. You were given a list of numbers and had to find out how many ways there were to divide this into three lists, maintaining the original order of the numbers, in some way that satisfied some condition (the sums for the three sub-lists had to be equal). I got started but soon noticed some test inputs failed. It turned out that empty sub-lists were also valid. I had **assumed** that each sub-list had to have at least one element. And then, of course, I'd need to consider whether my fixed program would handle inputs of 0, 1 or 2 numbers correctly as well.